# Query on Bilinear form

Tags: bilinear-form

We are given a bilinear form Q(x,y) = x'Ay.

Suppose Q(x,y)>=0 and A is non-singular. So can we then say that x'y>=0 ?

Is there any result/lemma to prove this claim ?

Comment: You should consider formatting your question and adding context. Also, what is $x'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I hope I understood your question correctly)

Try
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix},\quad y=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},\quad A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
$$
and you will see that
$$
Q(x,y)=x^TAy=1
$$
while
$$
x^Ty=-1.
$$

Comment: one may also make examples where $A$ is positive definite, still 2 by 2.

Comment: Yes, sure, there is a lot of freedom. With $$A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$$ and $x$ and $y$ as above, we will have that $x^TAy=-a$. This was just a simple example showing that the property asked for is not true.

Comment: Right. Taking  $x^T = (-1,9)$ and $y^T = (9,-1),$ then $A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{array} \right)$ worked. I think this OP is a little wobbly on the issue of inner products usually being positive definite and could use reinforcement on that issue